How to apply an xsl template for multiple conditions?
I'm trying to apply an xsl template based on multiple conditions such as:
Apply the same template if

a child of node exists OR
the node exists

e.g:
<root>
     <data>
         <test>VVV</test>
         <item>AAA</item>
         <item>BBB</item>
     </data>
</root>

I need to apply the same template under either of 2 conditions:

if data/item exists or
if data exists

After parsing through the root, tried the below:
<xsl:apply-templates select="data/item | data" mode="testMode" />
Expected result:
If data/item is present, then call the template at that element level, else, if data is present, call the same template.
But in my case, whenever data/item is present, its applying the template twice: first at data level then at the data/item level which is not as expected. Could anyone help on this?

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Your question makes no sense: if a node does not exist, then a child of the node cannot exist either. There is no OR about it. Please post your attempt along with the exact expected result in each possible scenario.

I need to first check if the child of node exists and apply the template at that level if it exists. If that child doesn't exists, then I need to apply the template at the node level itself. Although I try to apply the same template, the elements get fetched from inside child of node OR node based on whatever exists.

I am afraid I do not follow your explanation. Please post an example of the XML input in each possible scenario, along with the corresponding expected output. And  of course a full, executable XSLT showing your current attempt.

You can use e.g. <xsl:apply-templates select="data/item | data[not(item)]" mode="testMode" /> but obviously it is hard to tell whether you have the right template to handle both data as well as item elements as you didn't show the template(s?) you are talking about.
